# how to use multiple where clause?

Tags: mysql

Here is my code, I had to split it in three different codes, how can I combine these three into one, all come from same table.

code #1

```
select SUM(`Line_Total`) as Total,
    SUM(`_Revenue`) as Incr
     from `table 1`
     where `Month`='201909'
```

code #2

```
select SUM(`Channel`) as SKG
    from `table 1`
 where `Division`='Good'  and `Month`='201909'
```

code #3

```
select SUM(`Channel`) as Direct
  from `table 1`
  where `Division`='BAD' and `Month`='201909'
```

Please tell me how I can optimize the code and combine into 1 code only. as they all are in same table, but I dont know how to use multiple where clause with 3 sums

Comment: *where `Month`='201909'* Do you really think that month number (or name?) have 6 digits?

Comment: @Akina,  thats how our Months dB is stored. Please tell me how I can combine these 3 code into one.

Comment: Specify ONE DBMS. Show table's DDL. Show example data and the final result for that data.

Comment: Look in to IN clause: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: final o/p :   Total | Incr|  SKG  |  Direct                                                                               
                  200   | 145|  6658|   5556                for the month of September. I want my query to refresh every month

Comment: It is a good idea to provide sample data and desired output in questions like this (edit them into the main question text rather than giving them via "add comment"). There are at least two ways what you are asking for could be interpreted otherwise (one row per aggregate or one row per aggregate) and while one is more likely it is far from a given.

Comment: SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN _all_conditions_ THEN _field_to_sum_ END), ...

Answer (score 1):

Queries 2 and 3 read a subset of the rows already read by query 1 so you can easily combine them by using that as a base and moving the additional filters into `CASE` expressions.

```
SELECT SUM(`Line_Total`) AS Total,
       SUM(`_Revenue`)   AS Incr,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `Division` = 'Good' THEN `Channel` END) AS SKG,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `Division` = 'BAD' THEN `Channel` END) AS Direct
FROM   `TABLE 1`
WHERE  `Month` = '201909'
```

Comment: Im not sure if I explained it correctly, Query 2& 3 are sum of channels and where condition is on Divisions.

Comment: yes, that's what the query in my answer does, column `SKG` for example, will be the `SUM(Channel)` for rows meeting the combined `WHERE` and `CASE` expressions, i.e. equivalent to `where Division='Good'  and Month='201909'`

Comment: thanks it works !!